# Calculating market share in PowerBI with specific filter context

Tags: filter, powerbi, share

I am attempting to calculate market share in powerBI - but as soon as I drill into a level in my matrix the measure loses the filter context set by the filter.

I have created a simplified example - the measures we are using are more involved, with a lot more columns listed in the All Except function.

Sales Raw data looks like this:

| Product | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| Product1 | 50 |
| Product2 | 30 |
| Product3 | 18 |
| Product4 | 65 |
| Product5 | 94 |
| Product6 | 20 |
| Product7 | 54 |
| Product8 | 24 |
| Product9 | 145 |

There is a product master assigning Products to Brands and Categories:

| Product | Category | Brand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product1 | A | Brand1 |
| Product2 | A | Brand1 |
| Product3 | A | Brand1 |
| Product4 | B | Brand2 |
| Product5 | B | Brand2 |
| Product6 | B | Brand2 |
| Product7 | A | Brand3 |
| Product8 | A | Brand3 |
| Product9 | C | Brand4 |

I have a measure to calculate the "Market Size" based on the category filter selection:

```
MarketSize = CALCULATE(Sum(Sales[Sales])
,ALLEXCEPT(Sales
,ProductMaster[Category]
))
```

This functions as expected when viewing the shares at a brand level:

[image: Shares Working as Expected]

But as soon as I drill into a brand the total market value shifts from 355 to 176 - and the share of Brand 1 from 28% to 56%.  It is now ignoring the market value of Category B even though it is selected in the filter:

[image: Share not working as expected]

I want the share to still display as total of Category A & B - i.e. 28% when drilling into the hierarchy of the matrix.

I have created a simple PowerBI file to demonstrate - and uploaded to Google Drive
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CNl7rsB0OrL_TNxvh8DrxtpII3REx_tF/view?usp=sharing

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share a sample PBI file with what you are getting now? Because when I am trying the same here, I can find data as expected as below-

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response! 
I have shared a link to download my PowerBI file from Google drive in my question.  

The measure works as expected when expanding all (Brand) levels - but the problem arises when activating drill mode - and drilling into one brand.